# How to count total number of rows of an excel column using UFT/VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript

```
Set ExcelObj = createobject("excel.application")
ExcelObj.Visible = true
Set ExcelConfigFile = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open (Path)
Set Sheet = ExcelConfigFile.Worksheets("Scripts")
TotalRow = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

So far, I get total rows of the sheet. I have a column called "key". How can I count total number of rows in the key column?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to find number of rows in column - just change the Range("A1048576") to Range("B1048576")/Range("C1048576") etc to find individual row count for columns

```
Set ExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelObj.Visible = true
Set ExcelConfigFile = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\Work.xlsx")
Set Sheet = ExcelConfigFile.Worksheets("Scripts")
TotalRow = Sheet.Range("A1048576").End(-4162).Row 'xlUp = -4162
MsgBox TotalRow
```